# ollydbg opcode trace

Tags: debugging, assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ollydbg

Is there a way to save a trace of the opcode that is being executed (and not the command)?
I want to compare different trace runs, and using opcode trace (and not the evaluated commands) would give more reliable results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can

`view` > `Run trace`

in Run trace window right click and select `Log to file`

choose a file name.

until you tracing your file will complete.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Apparently OllyDbg 2.0 can: https://reversengineering.wordpress.com/category/tools/debugger/</strike>

I don't know if this was possible with the classic OllyDbg. But this plugin for hit tracing may be what you need: http://securitylabs.websense.com/content/Blogs/3144.aspx

Edit: not relevant, since the question is how to get the OPCODES, not the command trace. Sorry!

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I couldn't find any reference for saving "opcode trace" in the links above. In ollyDbg 2.0 there is only the native option of "command trace" and not "opcode trace". and the second link is not relevant either...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see now I misunderstood the question... :(